# Downsides to using an adapter allowing me to use car oil filter on motorcycle?

Tags: motorcycle, oil-filter

I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23cMne4iET4) recently on adding an aftermarket oil filter adapter to my motorcycle. Are there any downsides to using this type of product? Should I have a concern about using a car oil filter on my bike? If so, please specify the possible negative impact.

Comment: I really don't see as you will have any issues, though I'm not an expert in this area. You may want to ensure you get a "good" filter (way too many opinions on this, though). Secondly, the only thing which they did wrong in the video is they did not put a thin coat of fresh oil on the filter o-ring. This is a good way to ensure you **will** have a leak. This looks like a good alternative to paying gobs of money for manufacturer specific oil filters.

Comment: Unless designed properly, the adapter/filter combo could impact the oil pressure in the bike.  I have no experience with this product and can't comment on whether that is likely.  One question I have though is, why would anyone bother?  Re the Vstrom in the video, a Suzuki OEM filter is actually cheaper than the purolator filter shown in the video.  A larger, higher quality auto filter might have some benefit in extreme situations (dusty off road), but for road vehicles, it would be overkill IMHO.  So, if it isn't cheaper, and there is no benefit, why bother?

Comment: As long as the oil pressure Is correct, no problems. Adding the larger capacity filter will increase the cooling of the oil, keeping the viscosity at its prime range - which is life of the oil before breakdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An FYI it is a very bad idea to use automobile oil in your motorcycle. The reason behind this is because auto oil often has additives in it that when used in a motorcycle with a wet clutch (which most do) will wreak havoc on your clutch.

Given that, auto oil filters may be comprised of more fibers/elements that can perhaps cause higher/lower oil pressures in your motorcycle.

In my honest opinion, why risk such an investment like your motorcycle in saving a few bucks when buying an OEM filter?

Comment: I believe only energy conserving oils (labeled EC on the container) are a problem for wet clutch.  The EC oils include extra friction modifiers that make the oil a bit too slippery for some clutches.  I have used non-EC automotive oil in my SV650 (essentially just a smaller version of the Vstrom 1000 engine) for the last 9 years with no ill effect.

Comment: Based on other comments I think I may go ahead and give it a try in any case. I mean engine/oil/filter seems like these are similar requirements in any motor vehicle. If I can improve oil life then it might be worthwhile. I'll check other forums before making a final decision. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

For the original poster @Tommie C., do you know the thread size/pitch for the OEM Suzuki pipe where it goes into the engine? It seems like the pipe adapter from another Japanese bike engine such as Honda or Yamaha which both use the more common M20x1.5 on the filter side and have a separate thread (unknown pitch) may work for the engine side. The places that market the Suzuki adapter are apparently no longer in operation or do do not have the part for sale.